# Managing several FABs

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Looking at the Angular Material2 Spec, they clearly state where to place the FAB. However, I'm having trouble implementing it.

My project contains `md-sidenav` in the root component (app), and I would like to use FABs in its children components, but because they're contained in a `md-sidenav-container`, absolutely positioning something doesn't work as expected (I heard something about hardware acceleration and rewriting the axis, but if someone can explain that a bit more clearly - that would be great.

I went on the material docs and found this:

> *FABs inside sidenav:*
>
> For a sidenav with a FAB (or other floating element), the recommended
>   approach is to place the FAB outside of the scrollable region and
>   absolutely position it.

So I have some direction, but I'm not clear on how to manage this for many components and routes.

For completeness, I have included some of my code:

`app.component.html`:

```html
 <md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav>
  </md-sidenav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

`sample component.html`:

```html
<md-toolbar><md-toolbar>
<div class="page-content">
<!-- Page content starts here -->
</div>
```

If I were to follow the docs, my FAB would be placed in my `app.component.html`:

```html
 <button md-fab><md-icon>filter_list</md-icon>
 <md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav>
  </md-sidenav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

However, I don't want this button showing on ALL routes (as this is the case with the `app.component.html`), I want this button to show when a certain component (or route) is active.

What is the best way to implement (and manage -- show, hide, do something else, change icon) a FAB with a `md-sidenav-container` in the `app.component.html` across child routes and components?

I have considered the following approaches:

1. I could add a field to my `App State` called "currentComponent", and `ngOnInit`, each component can update this field through `App Service` ( function like: `this.appservice.newCompInit(this.componentName)` )
2. Could I generate (or "inject") a FAB on-the-fly to the app.component.html from the 'currentComponent' (currentComponent is a child of app.component)?

Other approaches are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by creating a separate `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and defining a fab component for each route.